# Parsing tweets from Twitter timeline using Python3.4: requests, Json and dictionaries

Tags: python, json, twitter, dictionary

My first Question :)
I'm learning to use api's with python, so I'm pulling my timeline tweets from twitter.
I have it successfully pulling data into a dictionary but the results format is different than my first project (different api), so I cannot work out what element to use to iterate through tweets.

```
import requests
import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1


url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?_count=3&screen_name=dimbodoyle&count=2'
auth = OAuth1('auth supplied'))

requests.get(url, auth=auth, verify=False)
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth, verify=False)
data = response.json()


# This is where the problems start
output = ''
for n in data:
    print(n)
    output += ['data'][n]['text'] + '\n'

with open('testTwitter.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(output)

print('Done')
```

When I run in python I get the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\twitter\Connecting to twitter with request and json.py", line 17, in 
    output += ['data'][n]['text'] + '\n'
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict.

Anyone any ideas? I get that it wants an integer to use for the loop and i get that n in this context seems to be the entire dictionary but I dont know why and I dont know how to correct it.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`n` is a dictionary containing the status rather than its index, so you would do `n["text"]` instead.

```
statuses = response.json()
print "\n".join([status["text"] for status in statuses])
```

Comment: Instead of `print "\n".join([status["text"] for status in statuses])`, the author would probably prefer `output = "\n".join([status["text"] for status in statuses])` because they plan on using it later to write to a file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so I have to hook onto one of the elements in the dictionary to parse through it?

Comment: Actually do either of you know how to do it in the form of the loop i had in my original code? This would be the easiest solution for me to understand...